# Процесс System сильно грузит процессор и Ssd, когда ноутбук Asus vivobook 16x находится на зарядке

Tags: windows, ноутбук

При нахождении ноутбука на зарядке, спустя 5-10 минут нахождения в простое, процессор начинает нагреваться до 70-75 градусов, диск начинает грузиться на 80%. При этом, если нажать на любую клавишу или подвигать мышкой, System сразу перестает грузить ноутбук.
Детальный просмотр процессов System через программу SysInternals Process Explorer показал, что грузит систему процесс "ntoskrnl.exe!KelnitializeDpc+0x1e0", однако, что это за процесс, в интернете найти не удалось.
Ноутбук был отдан в сервис, однако там эту проблему не обнаружили.
Пробовал отключать автоматический поиск обновлений, а также выполнять диагностику при помощи команды: "dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth", однако результатов это не дало.
Ноутбук с чистой системой, драйвера последней версии, установлены с официального сайта.
Отмечу, что когда ноутбук не подключен к зарядке, таких проблем нет

Comment: выполните проверку системного диска какими нибудь утилитами, типа CrystalDiskInfo

Comment: @ZxNuClear: Проверил диск через несколько утилит, в т.ч. через CrystalDiscInfo, проблем с диском нет